# Adding a y-axis label to secondary y-axis in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I can add a y label to the left y-axis using `plt.ylabel`, but how can I add it to the secondary y-axis?

```
table = sql.read_frame(query,connection)

table[0].plot(color=colors[0],ylim=(0,100))
table[1].plot(secondary_y=True,color=colors[1])
plt.ylabel('$')
```

Answer (score 482, accepted):

The best way is to interact with the `axes` object directly

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = np.arange(0, 10, 0.1)
y1 = 0.05 * x**2
y2 = -1 *y1

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()

ax2 = ax1.twinx()
ax1.plot(x, y1, 'g-')
ax2.plot(x, y2, 'b-')

ax1.set_xlabel('X data')
ax1.set_ylabel('Y1 data', color='g')
ax2.set_ylabel('Y2 data', color='b')

plt.show()
```

[image: example graph]

Comment: How to get the right y axis like the left one, I mean, from bottom to top, from 0  to 5, aligned.

Comment: How to rotate the blue text without overlapping the ticks?

Comment: @Sigur you have to mess with passing the horizontalalignment and/or verticalalignment parameter to ax2.set_ylabel

Comment: @PaulH, I found that we can get the y limits from ax1 and set it up to ax2, so the position of labels will be aligned.

Comment: @Sigur I don't follow how axes limits and ticks interact with label rotation, but if you're happy, godspeed

Comment: @wordsmith, I found solution for my 1st question, not for 2nd, about rotation.

Comment: Sigur first question: ax2.set_ylim(ax.get_ylim())
Sigur second question: ax2.set_ylabel('Y2 data', rotation=0, labelpad=<int>)

Hope this helps someone out.

Answer (score 47):

There is a straightforward solution without messing with matplotlib: just pandas.

Tweaking the original example:

```
table = sql.read_frame(query,connection)

ax = table[0].plot(color=colors[0],ylim=(0,100))
ax2 = table[1].plot(secondary_y=True,color=colors[1], ax=ax)

ax.set_ylabel('Left axes label')
ax2.set_ylabel('Right axes label')
```

Basically, when the `secondary_y=True` option is given (eventhough `ax=ax` is passed too) `pandas.plot` returns a different axes which we use to set the labels.

I know this was answered long ago, but I think this approach worths it.

Comment: Thanks - great approach! However, it is worth noting that this only works if you plot on the primary y-axis first, then the secondary y-axis, exactly as you have done. If you switch the order, it misbehaves.

Answer (score 19):

For everyone stumbling upon this post because pandas gets mentioned,
you now have the very elegant and straightforward option of [directly accessing the
secondary_y axis](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/visualization.html#plotting-on-a-secondary-y-axis) in pandas with `ax.right_ax`

So paraphrasing the example initially posted, you would write:

```
table = sql.read_frame(query,connection)

ax = table[[0, 1]].plot(ylim=(0,100), secondary_y=table[1])
ax.set_ylabel('$')
ax.right_ax.set_ylabel('Your second Y-Axis Label goes here!')
```

(this is already mentioned in these posts as well: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58047785) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18078496))

Comment: This is a matplotlib feature, not a pandas feature

Answer (score 13):

I don't have access to Python right now, but off the top of my head:

```
fig = plt.figure()

axes1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
# set props for left y-axis here

axes2 = axes1.twinx()   # mirror them
axes2.set_ylabel(...)
```

Answer (score 13):

Simple example with few loc:

```py
plot(y1)
plt.gca().twinx().plot(y2, color = 'r') # default color is same as first ax
```

Explanation:

```py
ax = plt.gca()    # Get current axis
ax2 = ax.twinx()  # make twin axis based on x
ax2.plot(...)     # ...
```