# formatting secondary y axis in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, yaxis, twinx

I am plotting a pandas DataFrame with several columns as below:

```
fig, ax = py.subplots(figsize=(11.7, 8.3))
df.plot(ax=ax, secondary_y=[A])
```

I can format the primary yaxis with a command as below:

```
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(FormatStrFormatter('%d days'))
```

How can I apply formatting to the secondary Y-axis (the one that displays on the right)?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can access the secondary ax with `ax.right_ax`. See the pandas docs on this: [Plotting on a secondary y-axis](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/visualization.html#plotting-on-a-secondary-y-axis).
So you can do like this:

```
ax.right_ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(FormatStrFormatter('%d days'))
```

Using matplotlib, you can also access it as `ax.twinx()`