# How to create a matplotlib graph with a secondary y-axis?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, graph

I would like to create a line graph using matplotlib, where `COMP` and `MKR` are on one axis, and `LEND`, `KNC` are on a secondary y-axis. The X-axis should be the date column. I only want dates from `2020-07-18` to `2020-07-20`. The below output is a pandas dataframe.

How can I do that? Thanks!!

```
              COMP   LINK    LEND    KNC     MKR
date                                            
2020-07-16  154.84  8.350  0.2766  1.571  443.10
2020-07-17  167.20  8.261  0.2883  1.636  449.49
2020-07-18  163.72  7.971  0.3110  1.826  454.50
2020-07-19  163.40  8.083  0.3534  1.689  465.80
2020-07-20  166.00  7.932  0.3519  1.710  461.10
```

Comment: You can find the solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14762181/adding-a-y-axis-label-to-secondary-y-axis-in-matplotlib

Answer (score 1):

You can use `loc` to extract data in the date range, and `plot`:

```
df.loc['2020-07-18':'2020-07-20'].plot(y=['COMP', 'MKR','LEND','KNC'],secondary_y=['LEND','KNC'])
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is there a way I can customize the y axis ranges for both the original and secondary axis? (i.e. say I wanted to make seconday axis vary from 0 - 1.2)