# Matplotlib scatter plot dual y-axis

Tags: python, matplotlib, scatter

I try to figure out how to create scatter plot in matplotlib with two different y-axis values.
Now i have one and need to add second with index column values on y.

```
points1 = plt.scatter(r3_load["TimeUTC"], r3_load["r3_load_MW"],
                     c=r3_load["r3_load_MW"], s=50, cmap="rainbow", alpha=1) #set style options
plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = [20,10]
#plt.colorbar(points)

plt.title("timeUTC vs Load")
#plt.xlim(0, 400)
#plt.ylim(0, 300)
plt.xlabel('timeUTC')
plt.ylabel('Load_MW')
cbar = plt.colorbar(points1)
cbar.set_label('Load')
```

[image]

Result i expect is like this:
[image]

So second scatter set should be for TimeUTC vs index. Colors are not the subject;) also in excel y-axes are different sites, but doesnt matter.

Appriciate your help! Thanks, Paulina

Comment: Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14762601/2246849) out.

Comment: @user2246849 thanks! this helped a lot. can you advise how to change from line to scatter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Continuing after the suggestions in the comments.

There are [two ways of using `matplotlib`](https://matplotlib.org/3.5.0/api/index.html#usage-patterns).

- Via the `matplotlib.pyplot` interface, like you were doing in your original code snippet with `.plt`
- The object-oriented way. This is the suggested way to use `matplotlib`, especially when you need more customisation like in your case. In your code, `ax1` is an [`Axes` instance](https://matplotlib.org/3.5.0/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes).

From an `Axes` instance, you can plot your data using the [`Axes.plot`](https://matplotlib.org/3.5.0/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.plot.html) and [`Axes.scatter`](https://matplotlib.org/3.5.0/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.scatter.html) methods, very similar to what you did through the `pyplot` interface. This means, you can write a `Axes.scatter` call instead of `.plot` and use the same parameters as in your original code:

```
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()

ax2 = ax1.twinx()

ax1.scatter(r3_load["TimeUTC"], r3_load["r3_load_MW"],
                     c=r3_load["r3_load_MW"], s=50, cmap="rainbow", alpha=1)
ax2.plot(r3_dda249["TimeUTC"], r3_dda249.index, c='b', linestyle='-')

ax1.set_xlabel('TimeUTC')
ax1.set_ylabel('r3_load_MW', color='g')
ax2.set_ylabel('index', color='b')

plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you! I didnt notice you answer before posting below. I found out that paratemter 'b-' or 'g-' (like in expample you linked) give error for scatter but works for line plots. Thanks again!:)