# Setting titles on chart with different scales

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, data-visualization

I am working with Matplotlib. Below you can see my data and plot.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.cm import get_cmap


data = {'year': [2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020, 2021, 2022, 2023],
        'open': [70, 20, 24, 150, 80, 90, 60, 90, 20, 20, 20, 24, 150, 80, 90, 60, 90, 20, 30],
        'closed':[30, 14, 20, 10, 20, 40, 10, 10, 10, 10, 30, 14, 20, 10, 20, 40, 10, 10, 10]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['year',
                                   'open',
                                   'closed'])


fig, ax_1 = plt.subplots(figsize = (8, 5))
ax_2 = ax_1.twinx()
cmap = get_cmap('tab10')

ax_1.bar(df['year'], df['open'], label = 'open', color = cmap(0))
ax_2.plot(df['year'], df['closed'], label = 'closed', color = cmap(0.1),linewidth = '4.5')

handles_1, labels_1 = ax_1.get_legend_handles_labels()
handles_2, labels_2 = ax_2.get_legend_handles_labels()

ax_1.set_ylim(0, 160)
ax_2.set_ylim(0, 45)
ax_1.legend(handles = handles_1 + handles_2, labels = labels_1 + labels_2, loc = 'upper left', shadow = True)
ax_1.grid(axis = 'y')
ax_1.set_title('Sales comparison')

plt.show()
```

This code produce plot as plot below.
[image]

Now I want to put titles on the places marked with yellow line with same names as data that showed `open` and `closed`. Also this chart have problem with decimal places on x-axis which need to be integer.

So can anybody help me how to solve this problem ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adding a y-axis label to secondary y-axis in matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14762181/adding-a-y-axis-label-to-secondary-y-axis-in-matplotlib)

Comment: Please don’t ask two unrelated questions per post!

Comment: @JodyKlymak I will ask everything that I want. If you can't provide answers please go to other questions. Thank you!

Comment: Stackoverflow expects one question per post and posts with multiple questions are subject to being closed.  I did provide an answer to your first question.  Both your questions are duplicates.

Comment: @Jody Klymak Please go to other posts and give your opinions. This question is regularly answered. Your opinion is not needed. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set y labels with [**`matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_ylabel`**](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_ylabel.html), one for each axes you used:

```
ax_1.set_ylabel('open')
ax_2.set_ylabel('closed')
```

And you can force x ticks to be integers with:

```
ax_1.xaxis.set_major_locator(MaxNLocator(integer = True))
```

### Complete Code

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.cm import get_cmap
from matplotlib.ticker import MaxNLocator


data = {'year': [2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020, 2021, 2022, 2023],
        'open': [70, 20, 24, 150, 80, 90, 60, 90, 20, 20, 20, 24, 150, 80, 90, 60, 90, 20, 30],
        'closed':[30, 14, 20, 10, 20, 40, 10, 10, 10, 10, 30, 14, 20, 10, 20, 40, 10, 10, 10]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['year',
                                   'open',
                                   'closed'])


fig, ax_1 = plt.subplots(figsize = (8, 5))
ax_2 = ax_1.twinx()
cmap = get_cmap('tab10')

ax_1.bar(df['year'], df['open'], label = 'open', color = cmap(0))
ax_2.plot(df['year'], df['closed'], label = 'closed', color = cmap(0.1),linewidth = '4.5')

handles_1, labels_1 = ax_1.get_legend_handles_labels()
handles_2, labels_2 = ax_2.get_legend_handles_labels()

ax_1.set_ylim(0, 160)
ax_2.set_ylim(0, 45)
ax_1.legend(handles = handles_1 + handles_2, labels = labels_1 + labels_2, loc = 'upper left', shadow = True)
ax_1.grid(axis = 'y')
ax_1.set_title('Sales comparison')

ax_1.set_ylabel('open')
ax_2.set_ylabel('closed')

ax_1.xaxis.set_major_locator(MaxNLocator(integer = True))

plt.show()
```

### Plot

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate it when people want to help.