Scaling plots to match shape
I am trying to distinguish a certain shape from a series of plots.
By doing so, I would be able to apply Hierarchical Clustering to cluster these plots into different categories based on their shape. I already wrote the code to create a distance matrix which I use for clustering.
My problem is that these individual plots have different ranges on the y-axis.
When plotting them, they have almost similar shape, but when plotting them together you can clearly see that they differ quite a lot.

And the individual plots:

What kind of scaler can I apply to compare these plots by their shape?
It's like taking a picture of the continuous plot and comparing those.
I cannot apply some form of polynomial fit since some plots differ in degree and I don’t want to go that way since I already explored it.

Is there a reason not to use multiple y-axes like here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14762601/18160754
